# Auto created teext when opening new html-page in Expression web

Tags: html

I'm learning to use Expression Web 4.0
When opening a new html-page, the following text is automatically created:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Is this code redundant, is this needed (or demanded by owners), or what?

Bent

Answer (score 2):

The **doctype** is used to tell the web browser the particular version of html used to create the web page.  It's also responsible for triggering a particular browser rendering mode. It is standardized by World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)

check the list of [DTD](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html)